# How to create circle image in pug file/css

Tags: html, css, pug

I am trying to make a circle image but it keeps showing as an oval. The only way I got it to work as a circle was by using this css code:

```
.teamImage {
 border-radius: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;}
```

However that shows  up way too small and also it is not centered. Example here: [image]

Using this css code I get a big elliptical shape:

```
.teamImage {
 border-radius: 50%;
   }
```

[image]

I want it to look like the second image, length/height wise but be in the shape of a perfect circle.

This is from the .pug file:

```
    .columns
      .column.is-one-third
        .card
          img(src='../images/team1.jpg', class="teamImage")
          .h3.is-3.title Jane Doe
          .p.title CEO & Founder
          .p Some example Text
          .button Contact
```

Comment: You need to use a larger square image to start with, then your 50% border radius will make a circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a border-radius, how about using a clip path over the image?

```
.teamImage { clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%) ; }
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: that worked but the top and bottom is slightly cut off some

Comment: Then change the first value to 40%, and see if that works better. The problem arises when you don't have consistent original image sizes. If all of your images were squares, it would be easier to make circles out of them. But sometimes we don't have the time or ability to edit the originals -- so solutions like border-radius and clip-path can help. They're not perfect, though.